# golang: время выполнения в цикле

Tags: golang

Почему при 100 повторениях (внешнего цикла) и внутреннем цикле на 1млн. или 10млн. итераций получаю: `Наименьшее значение времени выполнения (delta) =  0` Причём таких нулевых значений имею два-три десятка (посмотреть: `fmt.Println("   Отсортировано: ", arr_dlt, "\n ")`), а при других комбинациях повторений/итераций, - таких нулевых значений не бывает? Например: 100/100млн, или 10/1млрд или 10/1млн.
Код:

```
  package main

  import (
          "fmt"
          "sort"
          "time"
  )

func main() {

   fmt.Println("\n[ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -")
   var FlagLoopExt = true
   arr_dlt := []int{}
   //
   cnt := 100         // задаю кол-во повторений внеш.цикла;
   count := 1_000_000 // задаю кол-во итераций внутр.цикла;
   //
   for j := 0; j < cnt; j++ {
       ns1 := time.Now().UnixNano() // текущее местное время;

       i := 0
       for {
           i = i + 1
           if i == count {
               FlagLoopExt = false
           }

           if FlagLoopExt == false {
               break
           }
       }

       ns2 := time.Now().UnixNano() // текущее местное время;
       delta := int(ns2 - ns1)      // конвертировал int64 to int32
       arr_dlt = append(arr_dlt, delta)
       FlagLoopExt = true
   }
   //
   fmt.Println("Повторений (cnt) = ", cnt)
   fmt.Println("Итераций в каждом повторении (count) = ", count)
   //
   sort.Ints(arr_dlt) // сортирует от малого до большего;
   // чтобы потом посчитать среднее арифметическое значение):
   sum := 0
   for s := 0; s < cnt; s++ {
       sum += arr_dlt[s]
   }
   //
   fmt.Println("   Наибольшее значение времени выполнения (delta) = ", arr_dlt[cnt-1])
   fmt.Println("   Наименьшее значение времени выполнения (delta) = ", arr_dlt[0])
   fmt.Println("   Среднее значение времени выполнения    (delta) = ", sum/cnt)
   fmt.Println("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ]\n ")
   // fmt.Println("   Отсортировано: ", arr_dlt, "\n ")
}
```

Результат:

```
[ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Повторений (cnt) =  100
Итераций в каждом повторении (count) =  1000000
   Наибольшее значение времени выполнения (delta) =  1122300
   Наименьшее значение времени выполнения (delta) =  0
   Среднее значение времени выполнения    (delta) =  596182
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ]
```

Comment: потому что компилятор не глупый. он оптимизирует код за тебя

Comment: вероятно, это связано с различными факторами, например планировщик операционной системы и уровень нагрузки на систему, что приводит к временной приостановке или задержке процесса, поэтому часть итераций больше 0, а часть 0

Comment: все параметры - нули https://go.dev/play/p/VZDc0KpoWj3 потому что компилятор выкинул весь код

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причина разнобоя в показаниях заключается в том, что таймер в компьютере тикает с периодом, который значительно больше времени исполнения цикла. Значение `delta == 0` соответствует тому случаю, когда цикл завершился между двумя тиками таймера - таймер не тикнул, операционная система не обновила показания времени, `time.Now()` вернул одно и то же значение.

Значение `delta == 1122300` можно объяснить двумя причинами.

1. Таймер тикнул во время итерации, и время обновилось. Но величина задержки великовата.
2. Во время выполнения цикла произшло переключение процессов в ОС и ваша программа была остановлена. Пока управление вернулось, таймер успел натикать.

**КАК НАДО**

Данные никогда не анализируются по минимальному и максимальному значению. Нужно среднее, среднее квадратичное и распределение.

```
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "os"
    "sort"
    "time"

    "github.com/aybabtme/uniplot/histogram"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("\n[ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -")
    var FlagLoopExt = true
    arr_dlt := []int{}
    arr_float := []float64{}
    //
    cnt := 1000        // задаю кол-во повторений внеш.цикла;
    count := 1_000_000 // задаю кол-во итераций внутр.цикла;
    //

    for j := 0; j < cnt; j++ {
        ns1 := time.Now().UnixNano() // текущее местное время;

        i := 0
        for {
            i = i + 1
            if i == count {
                FlagLoopExt = false
            }

            if FlagLoopExt == false {
                break
            }
        }

        ns2 := time.Now().UnixNano() // текущее местное время;
        delta := int(ns2 - ns1)      // конвертировал int64 to int32
        arr_dlt = append(arr_dlt, delta)
        arr_float = append(arr_float, float64(delta))
        FlagLoopExt = true
    }
    //
    fmt.Println("Повторений (cnt) = ", cnt)
    fmt.Println("Итераций в каждом повторении (count) = ", count)
    //
    sort.Ints(arr_dlt) // сортирует от малого до большего;
    // чтобы потом посчитать среднее арифметическое значение):
    sum := 0.0
    sum2 := 0.0
    for _, delta := range arr_float {
        sum += delta
        sum2 += delta * delta
    }
    avg := sum / float64(cnt)
    std := math.Sqrt(sum2/float64(cnt) - avg*avg)
    //
    fmt.Println("   Наибольшее значение времени выполнения (delta) = ", arr_dlt[cnt-1])
    fmt.Println("   Наименьшее значение времени выполнения (delta) = ", arr_dlt[0])
    fmt.Println("   Среднее значение времени выполнения    (delta) = ", int64(avg))
    fmt.Println("   Среднеквадратичное отклонение          (delta) = ", int64(std))
    fmt.Println("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ]\n ")
    // fmt.Println("   Отсортировано: ", arr_dlt, "\n ")
    hist := histogram.Hist(10, arr_float)
    histogram.Fprint(os.Stdout, hist, histogram.Linear(10))
}
```

Я добавил вычисление среднеквадратичного отклонения и вывод гистограммы.

```
[ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Повторений (cnt) =  1000
Итераций в каждом повторении (count) =  1000000
   Наибольшее значение времени выполнения (delta) =  2648300
   Наименьшее значение времени выполнения (delta) =  0
   Среднее значение времени выполнения    (delta) =  959248
   Среднеквадратичное отклонение          (delta) =  405578
```

Что видно: время выполнения 0.9 мс +- 0.4 мс, то есть максимальное значение 2.6мс - это аномалия. Скорее всего, это результат переключения между процессами.

```
0-2.648e+05          10.3%  █▍           103
2.648e+05-5.297e+05  0.8%   ▏            8
5.297e+05-7.945e+05  1.8%   ▎            18
7.945e+05-1.059e+06  74.3%  ██████████▏  743
1.059e+06-1.324e+06  3.1%   ▌            31
1.324e+06-1.589e+06  4.5%   ▋            45
1.589e+06-1.854e+06  2%     ▎            20
1.854e+06-2.119e+06  2.8%   ▍            28
2.119e+06-2.383e+06  0.1%   ▏            1
2.383e+06-2.648e+06  0.3%   ▏            3
```

Это гистограмма. Максимум приходится на значения около 1мс. Я бы предположил, что это тоже переключения в контекст ядра, только без передачи управления другому процессу.

**Бенчмарк**

Специально экспериментов по времени выполнения в пакете `testing` есть поддержка бенчмарков. Этот пакет умеет справляться с аномальными выбросами и переключениями контекста операционной системой.

```
package main

import "testing"

func BenchmarkLoop(b *testing.B) {
    count := 1_000_000
    FlagLoopExt := false
    for j := 0; j < b.N; j++ {
        i := 0
        for {
            i = i + 1
            if i == count {
                FlagLoopExt = false
            }

            if FlagLoopExt == false {
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Запуск `go test -benchmem -run=^$ -bench ^BenchmarkLoop$ .`

```
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
pkg: example.org
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
BenchmarkLoop-8         1000000000               1.020 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      example.org     1.354s
```

Для верности можно прогнать бенчмарк 10 раз

```
go test -benchmem -run=^$ -bench ^BenchmarkLoop$ . -count 10
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
pkg: example.org
cpu: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
BenchmarkLoop-8         1000000000               1.044 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkLoop-8         1000000000               1.045 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkLoop-8         1000000000               1.028 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkLoop-8         1000000000               1.040 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkLoop-8         1000000000               1.031 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkLoop-8         1000000000               1.035 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkLoop-8         939725974                1.090 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkLoop-8         971966854                1.031 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkLoop-8         1000000000               1.034 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkLoop-8         1000000000               1.037 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
ok      example.org     13.554s
```

Видно, что ваш цикл достаточно стабильно завершается за 1.03 наносекунды на моей машине.

Comment: Понятно, большое спасибо за подробный ответ.